# What are warning quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

In some quests where you must slay a large monster there is a large question mark with "WARNING" written under it. What does that mean? I assumed it means there might be other monsters in the quest, but some of the things I've read online contradict this. I've also only seen other large monsters in a single warning quest (against the Qurupeco).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "Warning" you mean "Danger", in which case it means there is a chance for a Large Monster not normally part of the quest to randomly appear during the quest. It's  a good idea to bring along Dung Bombs on quests with a "Danger" warning, since throwing a dung bomb at a large monster will force it to relocate to another area.

Comment: It doesn't happen instantly, though.  So you still have to deal with it until the bomb makes it leave.

Comment: @fbueckert: The response time seems to vary from monster to monster. RAthalos leaves the area as soon as you toss a dung bomb at him, whereas RAthian takes a much longer time.

Comment: I wonder if they're cumulative, for those that don't leave right away.  ie: Deviljho crashes a party, and gets buried in poop.

Comment: Felyne Dungmaster and the Dungmaster armor skill can increase your chances of successfully dung bombing a monster as well as ensure success on any attempts to craft dung bombs.